# Taxonomy question

Tags: plugins, custom-taxonomy, custom-field

My php is very limited. I edit existing things to try and make it work and can usually understand more or less what code is doing but I can't write code myself.

I'll try to explain my situation.

I have a Woocommerce plugin that shows products as a list (in a table) instead of separate boxes. This table has a cell for the "name" of the product. I want to have the content of a taxonomy as a second line under each name on each row.

So let's say it is now (3 columns/row):

Row 1 :   Name 1                      |   Rating   |   Add To Cart Button
Row 2 :   Name 2                      |   Rating   |   Add To Cart Button

I want it to be:

Row1:     Name 1                      |   Rating   |   Add To Cart Button
              Taxonomy Country        |            |

Row2 :    Name 2                      |   Rating   |   Add To Cart Button
              Taxonomy Country        |            |

I did get this working years ago with a custom field using this line (in another plugin, Province being the custom field):
. get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Province', true ) .

Now, with the new plugin that does the same thing but is a lot better I want to do the same but this time with a Taxonomy instead of a Custom Field. (This allows me to set up filters based on taxonomy which I cannot do with the custom field)

I found the php file and place where it searches for and displays the content in the "name cell". Tried it out with just a plain "test" string and it showed "test" as I want it to as second line of each name cell. I then changed the code of the new plugin and added my old code (the  . get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Province', true ) . part) instead of the test string and again, works perfect.. shows the content of the custom field for each row as second line in the name cell...

Now I used a plugin to add a custom taxonomy, called it "country" and edited all my products to have the correct data in that new taxonomy.

All that remained was to change the line so that it reads the taxonomy instead of the custom field. And here is where I am stuck...

This is the full code for the custom field (works fine).

```
private function get_product_name( $product ) {
    $name = wcpt_get_name( $product ) . '</br><i>' . get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Province', true ) . '</i></td>';
    if ( array_intersect( array( 'all', 'name' ), $this->args->links ) ) {
        $name = WCPT_Util::format_product_link( $product, $name );
    }
    return apply_filters( 'wc_product_table_data_name', $name, $product );
}
```

How do I get the value from the taxonomy in there instead of the value from the custom field?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is to get your taxonomy terms using:

```
wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'yourTaxonomyName' );
```

This will return an array of WP Term Objects. Here's how you would get the first term name:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'yourTaxonomyName' );
$first_term_name = $terms[0]->name;
```

You can learn more about this method in the WordPress Codex:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms

Hope this helps :)

Updated:

```
private function get_product_name( $product ) {
    // Get all the country terms associated with $product.
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms($product->ID, 'country');

    // Set the empty $country string.
    $country = '';

    // Check if there are country terms available.
    if($terms){

        // If there are terms then use the first one to populate the $country variable. 
        $country = '</br><i>' . $terms[0]->name . '</i>';
    }
    // Add $country to the $name variable.
    $name = wcpt_get_name( $product ) . $country . '</td>';

    // This part could rewrite $name which would remove $country.
    if ( array_intersect( [ 'all', 'name' ], $this->args->links ) ) {
        $name = WCPT_Util::format_product_link( $product, $name );
    }

    return apply_filters( 'wc_product_table_data_name', $name, $product );
}
```

Comment: How do I add this to that code? because it has to be between those two "periods" to be displayed in the right place.. I mean this part:

$name = wcpt_get_name( $product ) . '</br><i>' . get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Province', true ) . '</i></td>';

I don't see how i can add two lines to that     "  . get post meta .... true) .   "     part.

Comment: I think you can easily insert the meta data by adding to your string like so:

Comment: try this:
`$terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'country' );
$name = wcpt_get_name( $product ) . '</br><i>' .$terms[0]. '</i></td>';`

Comment: Hello, here is the code I tried and the error I am getting:

private function get_product_name( $product ) {
      $terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'country' ); $name = wcpt_get_name( $product ) . '</br><i>' .$terms[0]. '</i></td>';
      if ( array_intersect( array( 'all', 'name' ), $this->args->links ) ) {
         $name = WCPT_Util::format_product_link( $product, $name );
      }
      return apply_filters( 'wc_product_table_data_name', $name, $product );
   }


ERROR:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$terms' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Comment: First, the wp_get_post_terms returns an array of Term Objects. So if you want to print the name you use _$terms[0]->name_.

Secondly, if there are no terms you will get an empty array so you probably should make sure that $terms is not empty before attempting to print $terms[0]->name.

Comment: I do not want to print the name, I just want to list the content of the taxonomy in that specific location. Why is this so hard compared to a custom field? Even seasoned php'ers can't seem to solve the issue :(

Comment: I think your request is unclear which makes it hard to provide a solution. What do you mean "list the content of the taxonomy"?

When you request the 'country' terms associated with the post you only get the terms that were checked when you edit the post. The name of that term would be the country you selected when editing. This is what you want, right?

Comment: The taxonomy is called "country". Each product has one "Germany" or "Spain" etc. I want "Germany" or "Spain" to be visible as the second row of the table cell. This worked with a custom field very easily using "get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Country', true )"... however I don't know how to do this with a taxonomy instead of a custom field.

Comment: When you select a taxonomy while editing a post your taxonomy selection gets saved as metadata. Using wp_get_post_terms() retrieves all the terms applied to the post.

So when you edit a post and choose the country "Germany" and then use the code above you will retrieve the name of the term applied to the post from the taxonomy country which is "Germany".

Comment: Okay, but can you solve this?

private function get_product_name( $product ) {
    $name = wcpt_get_name( $product ) . '</br><i>' . GERMANY . '</i></td>';
    if ( array_intersect( array( 'all', 'name' ), $this->args->links ) ) {
        $name = WCPT_Util::format_product_link( $product, $name );
    }
    return apply_filters( 'wc_product_table_data_name', $name, $product );
}

Where GERMANY should be replaced with the code that gives me germany right there...

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the method in your comment. I added a check to make sure a country is set. There will only be a line break if a country was set.

Comment: Hello, that looks really good code but it is not working. It gives me no errors at all but it doesn't add anything to the second line. Actually if I change this line:     $terms = wp_get_post_terms($product->ID, 'country');   if I change "country" with anything, for example:      $terms = wp_get_post_terms($product->ID, 'blablabla');  it does the exact same, no error but nothing on second line anywhere.. hmm maybe the "if" never triggers.. ill try and remove the if and see what happens..

Comment: removing the IF makes no effect... I tried changing . $terms[0]->name . to . test . and test does shows up on second line.. I think we are close..  I think the issue is in definitely in this part:     $terms = wp_get_post_terms($product->ID, 'country');

    // Set the empty $country string.
    $country = '';

        // Use the first one to populate the $country variable. 
        $country = '</br><i>' . $terms[0]->name . '</i>';

Comment: It seems like it is not populating the "country" variable with anything.

Comment: I usually confirm that I'm getting terms by printing out the returned array. try $country = '<pre>'.print_r($terms,true).'</pre>'; just before the $name declaration. This will give you a readable printout of the $terms array. If it's empty then there is no taxonomy set OR you have an issue with your taxonomy.

Comment: Hello again, here are the results, screenshot:
https://ibb.co/eQ2VSS

As you can see it shows something with array instead of the country and on the right I have the taxonomy properties. Maybe this helps.

Comment: I tried contacting the plugin author but he seems not willing to really provide detailed help, all he says is: "If it’s echoing out the word Array, then you need to go “deeper” into the variable than you currently are because you’re trying to echo an array instead of a string still. Basically there’s more to the item being used."

Comment: try echoing the array to see what's in it . . . simply put print_r($terms[0]->name,true) in place of $terms[0]->name to see the array contents. I'm guessing that you'll find 'name'.